Modelling the change between pairs of points vs longitudinal regression?

This is the basic Longitudinal Model (Mixed Effects), used to account for correlations between repeated measures in groups of individuals:

$$ y_{it} = X_{it}\beta + Z_{it}b_i + \epsilon_{it} $$
Where:

$y_{it}$ is the outcome for subject $i$ at time $t$
$X_{it}$ represents the fixed effects design matrix with corresponding parameters $\beta$
$Z_{it}$ is the random effects design matrix with subject-specific random effects $b_i$
$\epsilon_{it}$ represents the error term
$ b_i \sim N(0, \Sigma_b) $
$ \epsilon_{it} \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $


A first difference regression models the difference between two observations, allowing to minimize the impact of time-invariant omitted variable bias:

$$ \Delta y_{it} = \Delta X_{it}\beta + \Delta \epsilon_{it} $$
Where:

$\Delta y_{it} = y_{it} - y_{i,t-1}$ represents the change in the outcome
$\Delta X_{it} = X_{it} - X_{i,t-1}$ represents the change in predictors
$\Delta \epsilon_{it} = \epsilon_{it} - \epsilon_{i,t-1}$ is the differenced error term

I am just wondering if both models can be combined to create a mixed effects first difference regression model? For example:
$$ \Delta y_{it} = \Delta X_{it}\beta + Z_{it}b_i + \Delta \epsilon_{it} $$
$$ b_i \sim N(0, \Sigma_b) $$
$$ \Delta \epsilon_{it} \sim N(0, 2\sigma^2) $$
Is this acceptable to do in statistics? Combine the best of both worlds - allow for general correlation structures while additionally controlling for certain types of omitted variable bias?
